# Android ScrollView refuses to scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, scrollview

I have a root scrollview element with a relativelayout in it, and a bunch of form elements inside the relative layout.

For some reason, when the soft keyboard is up it seems unable to scroll all the way to the bottom, which cuts one of my buttons in half.

Here is a screenshot of the hierarchy viewer to demonstrate what I mean.

[image]

As you can see, the system knows that the view continues past the keyboard, yet the scrollview (which fills the visible part of the screen correctly) won't continue to scroll down as it should.

I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest for the activity, and I can/will not switch it to pan.

Any help is appreciated.

edit: I am seeing this in more than 1 view. Here is the xml of another view with the same problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="32dp" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reset_oldpass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/current_password"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reset_pass1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reset_oldpass"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/reset_new_pass"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reset_pass2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reset_pass1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/reset_confirm_pass"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reset_forgot_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reset_pass2"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/Link"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/Login_forgot_password" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset_reset_password_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reset_forgot_password"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:text="@string/reset_change_pass" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This also happens with `LinearLayout`. Thank you for providing this thread!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is truly strange, but it seems to be caused by `android:layout_margin="32dp"` within the RelativeLayout. Once I took it out the scroll worked properly.

Of course, because of this I had to add a bunch more margins to my form elements, but at least this is now fixed.

Comment: This is true. If your layout inside the ScrollView has margins you will not be able to scroll all the way to the bottom. For my case I could just put the margin in the root layout as I had a LinearLayout containing a scrollview and a button.

Comment: Thanks for your auto-response, it saved me from a lot of time !

Comment: padding on the scrollview would prevent the need to margin every element?

Comment: Padding on the child of my ScrollView (LinearLayout) ended up being the optimal solution for me. Shifting the margin to the ScrollView itself works in a way, but causes the scroll bar to have a margin with the edge of the screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by using padding in the ScrollView instead of margin in RelativeLayout.

So, remove `android:layout_margin="32dp"` from RelativeLayout(the child of ScrollView) and add `android:padding="32dp"` to the ScrollView.

Comment: This was the more appropriate solution than to go and divide out the margin in the child elements.  The margin just needs to be placed in the appropriate location; the ScrollView itself instead of the layout element it surrounds.

Comment: just said this without noticing the comment or the date of this post xD

Comment: In case this helps someone else, I also encountered this bug when I put the padding on the `ScrollView`. The only thing that worked for me was putting padding on the `ScrollView`'s child.

Answer (score 2):

Making status bar transparent in lollipop and above was creating the problem for me. Setting

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

to the parent view of layout containing scrollView solved the issue.

Comment: This needs more likes :) Worked much better than fiddling around with margins etc

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with an app and found out that it was due to the ScrollView layout_height being set to wrap content. The issue is that if you have enough content to need a ScrollView, you don't want to wrap the content because the bottom of the ScrollView is off the screen by some arbitrary amount. I didn't have enough data to be affected by this as I didn't need a ScrollView until the keyboard popped up. By the looks of it, the OP was in the same situation.

Now, once the keyboard pops up, the bottom of the ScrollView is raised the same amount as the height of the keyboard and ends up below the top of the keyboard by the same arbitrary amount that it was below the bottom of the visible screen.

Ultimately, my fix was to bind the top of the ScrollView to my toolbar and then right-click the ScrollVIew in the tree and select 'center vertically' (not in parent option). Now works like a charm. The layout_height should automatically go to 0dp.